# WSO2 EI - How to parametrize OAuth2 default mediator

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I am using the OAuth2 mediator in WSO2 EI 6.6 and I would like to parametrize this mediator parameteres: user, pass, url. I fail to set this values from properties.

Here is the xml of this mediator.

```
   <property name="ISurl" value="https://localhost:9445/services/"/>
         <property name="ISuser" value="admin"/>
         <property name="ISpass" value="admin"/>
         <oauthService remoteServiceUrl="$ctx:ISurl/" username="$ISuser" password="$ctx:ISpass"/>
```

The error shown is

```
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The system cannot infer the transport information from the $ctx:ISurl/OAuth2TokenValidationService URL.
        at org.apache.axis2.description.ClientUtils.inferOutTransport(ClientUtils.java:86)
```

Is there a way to parametrize this parameters to avoid options like code customizations at compiling time?

Comment: Looks like you are using a custom mediator. Is that so?

Comment: No, it is the standard oauth2 mediator. this is its xml.

Comment: "parametrize this parameters" can you explain this a little bit? What are you expecting?

Comment: I need to change it in runing time. Now I have to set it in compiling time and re-compile and deploy if user/pass change.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a class mediator implementation, it should have expression support[1]. Hence you should be able to parameterize this parameters using runtime properties. Something like below.

```
<class name="org.soasecurity.oauth2.scope.validator.OAuth2ScopeMediator">
            <property expression="$ctx:username" value="user"></property>
</class>
```

[1] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Class+Mediator

Comment: You are right, but the xml was not correct, sorry. I have edited the question with the default OAuth2 mediator  XML and the error shown.